# ColorHelper for emacs?

Tags: colors, emacs

I'm looking for a clone of [ColorHelper](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper) for Emacs. I know about rainbow-mode. But instead of coloring the color's background. I'm looking for a package that would add a little box next to it, just like ColorHelper [does it](https://packagecontrol.io/readmes/img/c41d41533c5c2ce938bf5bc7027deac45d884580.gif). I know I'm picky here, just wondering if such package exists or how difficult it would be to write it.

Comment: I would recommend starting with the color-picker libraries written by Drew Adams (faces+, eyedropper, palette) and then modify anything that is not to your liking to whatever suits your needs.  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorPalette

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it was answered over on the Emacs Stackexchange at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/are-there-color-pickers-for-emacs